# What is the right way to format to a circular buffer and flush to a file

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

I made a file class that has its own fixed length internal buffer as a drop-in replacement for the CRT file. I want to add a format method to the file class which will use fmt to format to the internal buffer. When the buffer is full, it needs to flush it to the file and continue formatting from the beginning of the buffer. The goal is an improvement in performance by reducing allocations, copying, and branches (`push_back`) but still being just as easy to use as a call to `fmt::format`.

I was able to do this in a hacky way as a proof of idea by modifying the `grow` method and `capacity` value in `iterator_buffer`:

Modifications:

```
template <typename T> class iterator_buffer<T*, T> final : public buffer<T> {
 protected:
     FMT_CONSTEXPR20 void grow(size_t) override
     {
        std::cout << "FLUSH: " << std::string_view{&*this->begin(), &*this->end()} << '\n';
        buffer<T>::set(&*this->begin(), 32); buffer<T>::clear();
     }

 public:
  explicit iterator_buffer(T* out, size_t = 0) : buffer<T>(out, 0, 32) {}

  auto out() -> T* { return &*this->end(); }
};
```

Main code:

```
std::array<char, 32> buffer; // the actual buffer is much larger

auto out = fmt::format_to(buffer.data(), "example format string 0x{:016X}. {} {} {} {} ", 0x99, "this could have some", "somewhat", "very long", "data in reality");

std::cout << "CLOSE: " << std::string_view{ buffer.data(), out } << '\n';
```

Output:

```
FLUSH: example format string 0x00000000
FLUSH: 00000099. this could have some
FLUSH: somewhat very long
CLOSE: data in reality
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: doesn't `std::ofstream` with `std::basic_filebuf` already do that?

Comment: I don't really see how the code comes, afaict from [`std::format_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_to) it is simply a output iterator. So just flush when the on-pass-the-end is accessed and back to first slot seems sufficient.

Comment: What kind of circular buffer?  If the circular buffer is based on links, you'll have to iterate through the list.  With an array based circular buffer, you can use `ostream::write` to block write elements to the stream.

Comment: @MarekR `std::ofstream` has an internal file buffer, but I don't think I can format directly to it (I would have to format to a buffer first and then call `ofstream::write` to copy the data into the stream buffer).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm just using an array buffer. The reason I'm trying to avoid `ostream::write` is two-fold. First, I can avoid a copy from some original `format_to` buffer into the stream buffer. Second, at least on MSVC, I don't believe I can change the stream buffer size, but I'd like a larger buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::ofstream`'s buffer mechanism directly, it also provide a way to [let you specify the buffer you want](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf).

```
void foo(){
    std::array<char, 32> buffer;
    std::ofstream file;
    file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer.data(), buffer.size()); // set the buffer
    file.open("file.txt");
    
    std::format_to(
        std::ostreambuf_iterator(file), // use the buffer as iterator
        "example format string 0x{:016X}. {} {} {} {} ", 
        0x99, 
        "this could have some", "somewhat", 
        "very long", "data in reality"
    );
}
```